# Pasting in design view in Dreamweaver( after clicking in code view)

Tags: view, dreamweaver, paste, cs4

I want to paste raw html in design view after end position of an object which I'll set by clicking in code view, -- how to do it?

I'm using Dreamweaver cs4 ver10

Comment: Why not just paste the raw html in code view, given you're setting the target point in code view? If it's raw html code, wouldn't it work better to paste in code view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the HTML that is pasted into the Design View to not be rendered, but rather be the "plain text" of the HTML displayed in the page (as in you want to show a code sample in your page), then if you are in split view and have an insertion point in Code View, use View -> Switch Views (CTRL+`) and that should place the focus into the Design View, and you should be able to paste your code.